# Gracefully Terminating a process when its controlling shells gets killed

Tags: c, linux, unix, signals, solaris

I have a command line application. The issue I am facing is that sometimes the users of that application close directly the terminal in which our application is running that also using the below command:

```
kill -9 pid_of_parent_console
```

I the above case our application should close gracefully by doing all the necessary cleanup. For that I wrote a signal handler for handling SIGHUP signal as when controlling terminal of process exits it sends SIGHUP to processes running under it, which we have handled to exit our process gracefully.But the thing is if user open a terminal suppose that is by default bash and then he again types bash command in it then run our application and if suppose kills that applications parent process that is bash executed manually after opening terminal then our application doesn't gets SIGHUP and does not exit gracefully.For simplicity I have written the below code which reproduces the issue:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

FILE *fp = NULL;
int flag = 1;

void handler(int signum)
{
    flag = 0;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGHUP, handler);
    // just for testing
    fp = fopen("file", "w");

    // loop terminates only when HUP is generated
    while (flag);

    // if SIGHUP is generated then code should reach here
    // and write the below in file.
    fprintf(fp, "SIGHUP Generated");

    fclose(fp);
return 0;    
}
```

For simplicity I am not using sigaction for handling signals.

What I have observed is that when I open a terminal and press tty command  and note the name of stdin file associated with it, and then when in the same terminal if I enter bash command and again if I note down the stdin file associated with it using tty command, what I found out is that both the bash shells, one that opens by default when I launch terminal and one I manually opened by typing bash command in bash console share the same stdin file name.

So, due to which when I kill that second bash which is parent of my process the stdin file associated with it doesn't gets closed and I think thats why I am not receiving SIGHUP signal.

Is there any other way I can use to kill my process too gracefully when its controlling console gets killed.

Terminal emulator used: GNOME Terminal 2.31.3
Default shell: bash

Comment: Which shell do you use?

Comment: I tried in tcsh and bash

Comment: Since signal 9 is not trappable, your terminal does not get the opportunity to do any cleanup, which would be where it would generate a HUP to child processes. You'll need to re-educate your users to not use `kill -9`. Possibly with extreme measures...

Comment: @twalberg but why the same is working with LINUX there also i did with kill -9 only and also if I close the terminal using cross button still it didn't generates the SIGHUP signal.

Comment: Killing a window via the window manager decorations likely sends SIGTERM instead of SIGHUP, but this may vary based on which GUI you are using (and maybe even in different versions of a single GUI). Regardless, SIGKILL (a.k.a `kill -9`) should only be used rarely, after exhausting other possibilities.

Comment: @twalberg so any alternative i can use to end my process if its terminal got killed somehow.

Comment: @mSatyam Your process could periodically check for its PPID (parent PID) and act upon its change (to "1"), which would mean that the parent process died/crashed/etc.

Comment: @mafso I made a wrong observation earlier could you please see the post now.

Comment: It might help if you state what your default shell is and what terminal emulator and window manager you use under Solaris.

Comment: @jlliagre actually I was wrong about my previous assumption the issue is occurring in every UNIX based system not only solaris. though i will update information as you said. Also I have completely changed the post could please read it again in order to reproduce issue.

Comment: You really should educate your users. Even if you handle the case of the parent process killed by `-KILL` you won't be able to handle the case of *your own process* killed by `-KILL` and your users are able to kill it likewise!

Comment: thanks a lot @BasileStarynkevitch I truely agree to your point and also all others point too...Could you specify your comment in a small answer such that I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

Regardless of the OS, `SIGKILL` (i.e. signal `-9`) is directly handled by the kernel and the process is killed before any userland handler had a chance to process anything. This is true for the Linux kernel just like the Solaris one.

There is then no way for the target process to protect itself against that signal (outside intercepting it on the sender side or in the kernel).

On the other hand, closing a terminal emulator window send an XEvent to it. Before exiting, the terminal emulator should probably send a SIGHUP signal to your process.

I would suggest to use dtrace on the Solaris 10 machine to investigate this process. Start with this script which show all signals sent: http://www.brendangregg.com/DTrace/kill.d

Comment: are you telling that even if a LINUX terminal terminated with SIGKILL will not send SIGHUP to its childs....though thanks for the script I will try it and let you know.

Comment: That's indeed what I'm telling, however, the kernel itself might send a SIGTERM to the terminal child processes if they are part of a group of processes which session leader is killed. That's likely what you are observing under Linux.

Comment: under LINUX terminal childs are indeed receiving SIGHUP signal when terminal got killed as I mentioned in my post too not SIGTERM.

Comment: I made a wrong observation earlier could you please see the post now